# Highrise API - get emails from the last X days

Tags: php, api, highrise

has anyone come across an example how to find a list of emails in a Highrise app dating back X days?

We have a large database of customers and the solution I had in mind:

- get all people
- get emails for each of them
- parse results / filter by date

seems too inefficient

maybe getting the last email ID and traverse back until -X days would be better?
Is it possible to find the last email ID then?

I do not care which API wrapper to use, but have been playing with https://github.com/AppSaloon/Highrise-PHP-Api

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, but one idea would be to use Recordings, see...

https://github.com/37signals/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/recordings.md

...so you could work your way back through recent activity using this, just pulling out emails and ignoring the notes and comments.

I use the [same wrapper you mention](https://github.com/AppSaloon/Highrise-PHP-Api), and it's probably the best route really, if PHP is your lingua franca. That said, I don't think it supports the Recordings API functionality, though it would be quite easy to add it to the feature-set.